# Linkable <Div> Overlay on iframe Video | Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently on an App where users can upload Clips from Vine and Instagram.

I'm retrieving those clips on my Index like Pinterest calls its Pins, in a Masonry.

But i need an `Overlay` so when people click on the Clip it redirects them to the clips page (Like the link_to i did in the clip.title).

How can i overlay the iframe with a linkable div ?

I'm displaying the clips on my Index page like so:

```
    <div class="clip-box">

  <% if clip.vine_link.present? %>
    <iframe class="vine-embed"
            src="https://vine.co/v/<%= clip.vine_link %>/embed/postcard"
            width="200" height="200" frameborder="0"
            allowtransparency="false">
    </iframe>

  <% else %>

    <iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/<%= clip.instagram_link %>/embed/"
            width="190" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
            allowtransparency="false">
    </iframe>

  <% end %>


  <p class="clip-title">
    <%= link_to clip.title, clip %>
  </p>

  <p class="clip-uploader pull-left">
    <strong>
      <%= link_to clip.user.user_name, clip.user %>
    </strong>
  </p>

</div>
```

With the Css:

```
.clip-box {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  float: left;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clip-title {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.clip-uploader {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Simons answer worked.

My Working Div

```
<div align="center iframe-div" style="position: relative;">

      <!-- Instagram Video -->
      <%= link_to "", clip, class: "iframe-link" %>
      <iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/<%= clip.instagram_link %>/embed/"
              width="190" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
              wmode="Opaque" class="video-iframe" allowtransparency="false">
      </iframe>
    </div>
```

with the Css:

```
.iframe-link {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: white; opacity: 0.5;
}

.iframe-div {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just finished doing this over a youtube video, just float a div on top of your frame.

Check my fiddle for the code I used: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym5w8/

Place the iframe and the link inside a container like so:

```
<div align="center" class="container">
    <a href="http://thelink" class="the-click"></a>
    <iframe wmode="Opaque" class="video-iframe" width="100%" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ZauRZNs8BMg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Then style the container to have position relative for IE support then float your link:

```
.the-click {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Hey Simon, i Tried This but it didn't seem to work for me. I updated my Question with the Code. Can you give it a Look ?

Comment: The updated code with my answer is missing a lot of important stuff. The div that is around the click and iframe should have the following css "position: relative;" and also please show the css you are using for "iframe-link"

Comment: Make sure <div align="center"> that is holding the iframe and link is "<div align="center" style="position: relative;">" and then add css for "iframe-link" with: "position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 999; background-color: white; opacity: 0.5;"

Comment: Please can you also post the html outcome of your code? So I can view it, with the css classes you are using

Comment: It worked Simon, i had to edit my link. Now its working perfect. Thanks :)